# PHP/JSON Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, arrays, json

*** EDIT ***

Actually figured out the problem thanks to @h2ooooooo. Turns out that I had one object in my game array that was structured differently than the others

---

I have the following PHP code that I can't seem to get working. I keep getting the error...

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

...on my if statement. However, the following statement prints just fine under the for loop:

```
echo $user->fantasy_content->users->{0}->user[1]->games->{$i}->game[0]->season;
```

Here is the code I'm running where $user is a json array

```
        for($i = 0; $i < $count;$i++) {
            if($user->fantasy_content->users->{0}->user[1]->games->{$i}->game[0]->season > 2013) {
                echo 'Hi'.$user->fantasy_content->users->{0}->user[1]->games->{$i}->game[0]->game_key;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: Either `$user->fantasy_content->users->{0}->user` isn't an array or `$user->fantasy_content->users->{0}->user[1]->games->{$i}->game` isn't an array.

Comment: There is an option to `json_decode()` to create an associative array instead of objects - maybe that is what you want?